# Define custom probability density function in Python

Tags: python, statistics, probability

Is there a way, using some established Python package (e.g. SciPy) to define my own **probability density function** (without any prior data, just $f(x) = a x + b$), so I can then make calculations with it (such as obtaining the variance of the continuous random variable)? Of course I could take, say, SymPy or Sage, create a symbolic function and do the operations, but I'm wondering whether instead of doing all this work myself I can make use of an already-implemented package.

Comment: Thanks for an easy way! How do you generate a histogram of random numbers implementing this way of defining custom distribution function?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to subclass the [rv_continuous](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) class in scipy.stats

```
import scipy.stats as st

class my_pdf(st.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x):
        return 3*x**2  # Normalized over its range, in this case [0,1]

my_cv = my_pdf(a=0, b=1, name='my_pdf')
```

now my_cv is a continuous random variable with the given PDF and range [0,1]

Note that in this example `my_pdf` and `my_cv` are arbitrary names (that could have been anything), but `_pdf` is *not* arbitrary; it and `_cdf` are methods in `st.rv_continuous` one of which must be overwritten in order for the subclassing to work.

Comment: @GertVdE: What does "self" in def _pdf do??

Comment: @Srivatsan: see [the answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Comment: There is a problem with the normalization, here: you need to give a _normalized_ probability distribution function (`3*x**2`, here), or the resulting random variable yields incorrect results (you can check `my_cv.median()`, for example). I fixed the code.

Comment: @EOL i'm finding your use of the term "normalized" confusing.  what's needed, i believe, is for the function to be centered at 0 and scaled to 1.  but this answer seems to imply that the normalization needs to be over the range of `x` [0, 1].  can you clarify?

Comment: follow-up question: how would i draw random samples from my defined variable?

Comment: @dbliss: "normalized" in the sense of a normalized probability distribution function: its integral over the range of possible values ([0,1], in this case) should be 1.

Comment: Maybe the standard way is to use `my_cv.rvs()` (which can take a `size` argument, for obtaining multiple samples in one go). This is what I guess from the documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous).

Comment: @EOL gotcha.  it wasn't clear to me whether the [0, 1] thing was meant to be specific to this case or a generally necessary thing.

Answer (score 19):

You should check out sympy.stats. It provides an interface to deal with random variables. The following example provides a random variable `X` defined on the unit interval with density `2x`

```
In [1]: from sympy.stats import *
In [2]: x = Symbol('x')
In [3]: X = ContinuousRV(x, 2*x, Interval(0, 1))

In [4]: P(X>.5) 
Out[4]: 0.750000000000000

In [5]: Var(X) # variance
Out[5]: 1/18

In [6]: E(2*cos(X)+X**2) # complex expressions are ok too
Out[6]: -7/2 + 4⋅cos(1) + 4⋅sin(1)
```

If you're interested this abstraction can handle some fairly complex manipulations.

Comment: Wow... this is just awesome! Thank you very much for this contribution. I'll keep an eye on this and your blog