# Define continuous, non-analytical pdfs in python

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I am planning to do some basic algebra on continuous, non-analytical random variabels. I want to define their probability density functions as arrays x and f(x).

Yet, I was surprised to find out that there does not seem to be any package that does basic operations like computing sum- or product distributions of two pdfs (please correct me if I'm wrong).
To implement those operations by myself, I then planned to create a subclass of scipy.stats rv_continuous, following [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/define-custom-probability-density-function-in-python) thread:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

class my_pdf(sp.stats.rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self,x,p):
        self.x = x
        self.p = p
    
    def _pdf(self,x):
        return sp.interpolate.interp1d(self.x,self.p)(x)

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
f = 3*x**2
my_cv = my_pdf(x,f)
my_cv.pdf(0)
```

However, overwriting the **init** method is probably not the way to go. Is there a way to add additional parameters to rv_continuous, or another way to approach the problem, other than building everything from scratch?

Comment: This is probably better suited for StackOverflow

Comment: the linked question was well answered in this forum, and I feel like scientist should be much more interested in pdfs than developers. However I'll try it, and post the answer here if I get one. thx

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with statistics and everything to do with how Python loads and overwrites modules

Comment: I don't even know if I am on the right track here using rv_continuous, so any other approach is warmly welcome, too

Comment: This question was answered on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64615973

Comment: Indeed, I did not post the answer here. So you were right about SO, thanks for your hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone stumbles over this again, it got answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615973/loading-additional-parameters-to-scipys-rv-continuous):

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

class my_pdf(sp.stats.rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self,x,p):
        super().__init__(a=x.min(), b=x.max())
        self.x = x
        self.p = p

    def _pdf(self,x):
        return sp.interpolate.interp1d(self.x,self.p)(x)

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
f = 3*x**2
my_cv = my_pdf(x,f)
my_cv.pdf(0)
my_cv.cdf(0.5)
```

Still, I feel like there should be a package for operations on this kind of random variables?